# I need to polyfill nullish-coalescing-operator and optional-chaining

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills, babel-polyfill, core-js

I have an angular application which I recently upgraded to angular 15. I have a requirement to support it in Chrome 69 browser. When I run in Chrome 69, I get 2 errors which are related to the optional-chaining and nullish-coalescing-operator.

Could someone tell me what I need to add to my polyfills.ts file to support these operators in Chrome 69. I know babel has some plugins to support this and we can polyfill using it, but I don't want to use Babel unless it is the only option. Can I do it using core-js?

I tried the adding following lines in my **polyfills.ts** file:

```
import 'core-js/features/nullish-coalescing-operator';
import 'core-js/features/optional-chaining';
```

But, my code doesn't compile. I get the below error:

```
 Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/nullish-coalescing-operator'
 Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/optional-chaining'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Edit:
As per the core-js official documentation https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#babelpolyfill I can use core-js for polyfills instead of @babel/polyfill. I already have the below 2 lines in my polyfills.ts file

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

Please let me know what else I need to add support for nullish-coalescing-operator and optional-chaining?

Comment: Do you have the `core-js` installed ?

Comment: Yes, I have core-js installed in my project. My package.json has this entry "core-js": "^3.2.24", under the dependencies. So, it is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

These patches don't exist in `core-js`.

More over, this can't be polyfiled as both are syntactic sugar. Babel isn't polyfilling but transpiling.

Comment: So, what options do I have? Do I have to use Babel and transpile it to support those 2 operators?

Comment: Yes only a transpiler like Babel can do this.